# How to set number of columns for build monitor view in jenkins job DSL groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, dsl

Creating Build Monitor view with DSL Script, but there is no detail onto how to set the number of columns.

Using https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/buildMonitorView documents for some insight. Thinking the configure function may allow but I still have the same question of how to do it.

Assumed it may have been like list view and add a column to it but this does not work.

My current code so far:

```
buildMonitorView('Automation Wall') {
    description('All QA Test Suites ')
    recurse(true)
    configure()
    columns(1)
    jobs {
        regex(".*.Tests.*")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
buildMonitorView('Automation Wall') {
    description('All QA Test Suites ')
    recurse(true)
    configure { project ->
        (project / columns ).value = 1
    }
    jobs {
        regex(".*.Tests.*")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more description